# How to do multiple replace with a regex where the term to replace is stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which looks like below

```
givenText = "#0How #0much #0sales #0in #0batu #0where #0discount #0on #0sales?"
```

I have a dictionary which looks like below

```
termAssignment = {"sales": "#4", "batu": "#2"}
```

Now I want to replace the terms in the string which matches the keys of the dictionary. But as you can see, the two terms in the string that matches the keys are `sales` and `batu`. But I also want to replace the `#n` that is associated with the terms.

So basically the end result should be

```
"#0How #0much #4sales #0in #2batu #0where #0discount #0on #4sales?"
```

So if I do something like this

```
for(word in termAssignment) {
      if(givenText.includes(word)) {
          replaceTerm = "#0" + word
          givenText = givenText.replace(/replaceTerm/g, termAssignment[word] + word)
      }
  }
```

But it doesn't do anything since the I need to apply `global` replace on a string and I have that string assigned to a variable.

How can I associate regex with a variable and do replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the keys by `|`, pass to `new RegExp`, with `#\d+` on the left, then use a replacer function. Make sure the part after the `#n` is in a lookahead and capturing group, then look up the matched capture group (the key)'s value on the object, and replace with that value:

```js
const givenText = "#0How #0much #0sales #0in #0batu #0where #0discount #0on #0sales?";
const termAssignment = {"sales": "#4", "batu": "#2"};
const pattern = new RegExp(
  `#\\d+(?=(${Object.keys(termAssignment).join('|')}))`,
  'g'
);

const result = givenText.replace(pattern, (_, key) => termAssignment[key]);
console.log(result);
```

For this case, the generated pattern will be:

```
#\d+(?=(sales|batu))
```

It matches `#`, followed by one or more digits, then captures the word that follows for use in the replacement. In the replacement function, the whole match, eg `#0`, in the `_` variable, is not used, but the second argument is what's contained in the first capturing group, so it'll be `sales` or `batu`. So all you need to do is look up what property on the object and return it so the `#n` part is replaced with the appropriate number.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `split` and `map`, without the need for a `RegExp`. Something like:

```js
const givenText = "#0How #0much #0sales #0in #0batu #0where #0discount #0on #0sales?";
const terms = Object.entries({"sales": "#4", "batu": "#2"});
const parsed = givenText.split(` `)
  .map(v => {
    const term =  terms.find(t => v.includes(t[0]));
    return term ? `${term[1]}${v.slice(2)}` : v;
   })
  .join(` `);
  
console.log(parsed);

// can be simplified to
const parsed2 = givenText.split(` `)
  .map(v => `${(terms.find(t => v.includes(t[0])) || [``,`#0`])[1]}${v.slice(2)}`)
  .join(` `);

console.log(parsed2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```